# Select a drop down menu option using Selenium in Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu, timeoutexception

I'm trying to select an option in a drop down menu using Selenium, but I couldn't figure it out how to handle this Timeout exception

This is the html of the page:

```
<select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddUnidade" onchange="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddUnidade\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddUnidade" class="form-control" style="width:100%;">
        <option selected="selected" value="">-- SELECIONE --</option>
        <option value="1">MATRIZ</option>
        <option value="2">FILIAL</option>

    </select>
```

First I've tried this code:

```
select = Select(browser.find_element_by_id('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddUnidade'))
select.select_by_visible_text('MATRIZ')
```

Then I had this error:
ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element  could not be scrolled into view

I googled and found out the WebDriverWait solution. So, I tried this code:

```
select = Select(browser.find_element_by_id('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddUnidade'))
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddUnidade']//options[contains(.,'MATRIZ')]")))
select.select_by_visible_text('MATRIZ')
```

Then I had this:
TimeoutException: Message:

I googled again and there was another solution with EC.presence_of_element_located, but it didn't work either. I had the same TimeouException message.
Does anybody know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try below solution:

```
element= WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddUnidade")))
actionChains = ActionChains(driver)
actionChains.move_to_element(element).perform()
select = Select(element)
select.select_by_visible_text('MATRIZ')
```

**Note :** please add below imports to your solution

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

or

```
element= WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddUnidade")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", element)
select = Select(element)
select.select_by_visible_text('MATRIZ')
```

**Updated solution :**

```
element= WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddUnidade")))
actionChains = ActionChains(driver)
actionChains.move_to_element(element).perform()
select = Select(element)
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddUnidade']//options[contains(.,'MATRIZ')]")))
select.select_by_visible_text('MATRIZ')
```

Comment: Thanks Dipak! I tried both solutions and I had this message: ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <option> could not be scrolled into view

Comment: Dipak, thanks again!! But this time I had the TimeoutException: Message: on this line: WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddUnidade']//options[contains(.,'MATRIZ')]")))

Comment: share ur URL, I will check from my end